# What will be the number of ways of dividing 52 cards into 3 groups of 20,21 and 11 cards

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am getting confused if the number of ways to divide 52 cards into 3 groups of 20,21,11 should be 3!*multinomial coefficient term or just multinomial coefficient term? Since we do not know which group will get 21, 20 or 11 cards?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the case that we divide the cards into groups named A, B and C (or left, middle and right, or north, south and west, or ...), and one of those three groups has 21 cards, one has 20 cards and one has 11. Instead, we are told to divide the cards into one 21-card group, one 20-card group and one 11-card group.

We know exactly which of the three groups will have 21 cards: the 21-card group. This is why there is no 3! in the final answer. Admittedly, this is a vagueness in the language of combinatorics exercises that you will just have to get used to.

Comment: Got it! So basically I have to get used to the language. Because in one question it stated that we are unaware which room will 5 ppl, 2 and 1. To be on the safer side can I just apply the factorial term whenever the question asks?

Comment: @AMa In that other case, the rooms are already there to put people into, while in this case, there are no such "premade slots" to fit the groups of cards into (apart from the slots that actually dictate how many cards are in each group). Yes, it's a language thing, and I am convinced that combinatorics has some of the least friendly language of all of math (at least pre-university), with all its implicit expectations that you should just know how everything works without ever actually being told.

Comment: What if the question says 9 ppl into 3 office divisons of HR, ADMIN AND DEVELOPMENT. With 4 in one, 3 in other and 2 in last group. Do we use 3! Here or no? As question doesn't mention which division will have 4 people?

Comment: @AMa Again, it's a language thing. It depends on what you mean when you say "the last group". If it refers to the last of those three offices, then no, no 3!, as that implies that the sizes go in the same order as the offices. If it just refers to "the last of the three groups, whatever office that may be" (which is what I would say it means), then yes, that would use 3! but only because all the groups have different sizes. If all the groups were to have 3 people each, the 3! would go away. If the distribution were 2, 2, 5, then there would be just a 3, not 3!.